# Can I undo committing a file while keeping the changes unstaged?

Tags: git

I committed changes to a file (we'll call it `foo`) before I meant to.  (The changes are good; I just didn't mean them to be part of this pull request.)  The commit has been pushed, and I'm happy with all the other changes in the commits except to this file.  To compound the problem, I've done another commit (without `foo`) and push since then.

My local repo has no staged or unstaged changes.  Is there a way to simultaneously:

- Push the old version of `foo` (from `HEAD^^`) to the global repository.
- Have the new version of `foo` unstaged in my local repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `git stash` to stash all your local changes.

Then, transform `foo` into the form you want it to be, and make a commit and push.

Finally, use `git stash apply` to restore your working state.

---

**Update**. It appears that the OP wants to make a new commit which will restore an older version of `foo`, and pulling a slightly new version of `foo` into the working tree (unstaged).

This can be done with the following sequence of the commands. Assume that the `sha1` is the hash of the commit containing the older version, and `sha2` is the hash of the commit containing the newer version.

1. Pull out the old version that needs to be restored.

   ```
   git checkout sha1 -- foo
   ```
2. Commit and push.

   ```
   git commit 
   git push
   ```
3. Pull the newer version into the working tree.

   ```
   git checkout sha2 -- foo
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but I thought "git stash" didn't do anything if there have been no changes since the last commit, as in my case.

Comment: @espertus, You mentioned that the "latest version of foo" is unstaged, I assume that means the said version is not commited?

Comment: I'll try making my question clearer.  I meant that I wanted to move the latest version of foo ---> unstaged.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for bearing with me.

Comment: @espertus, No worries. Oftentimes explaining the question properly is as hard as finding the answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the "git add foo" is necessary?  I think that checkout on a file also stages it.

Comment: @espertus, You are right, it is not necessary. But I do it out of habit. :)

Comment: @espertus, I have removed it.